# Web browser header

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code:

```
    Dim TestHeader As String = "Referer: http://www.testrefferer.com"

    If chkRefferer.Checked = True Then
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(cmbUrl.Text, False, Nothing, TestHeader)
    Else
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(cmbUrl.Text)
    End If
```

Whenever I try and browse to a page with the 'TestHeader', IE opens up and goes to the page.... However, if I navigate to the same page without the additional header, it loads up fine in my webbrowser control.

Why would this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the 'False' to "_self" and it now works.